# Optimization problem about large matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, inverse

I'd like to solve the following optimization problem:
Find non-negative scalar $a$, $b$, $c$ to minimize

$\| (D-(aA+bB+cC+D^{-1})^{-1})y\|^2+2\operatorname{trace}((aA+bB+cC+D^{-1})^{-1})$

where $A$,$B$,$C$ are known large sparse positive semi-definite matrices, $D$ is a known diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements, and $y$ is a known column vector, and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes Euclidean norm.

Which optimization method or numerical method is the best (in terms of speed and complexity) to solve the problem?

Comment: I believe you mean $\| \cdot \|$ is the euclidean norm.

Comment: yep, you are right

Comment: Rephrasing: The first term in the objective function is a Euclidean norm of a vector and second term is a trace of a matrix. The minimum value of Euclidean norm is $0$ for a zero vector and Minimum value of Trace of a matrix is unbounded.  

Here the optimizing variables are non-negative scalars $a,b,c$.

Comment: @Learner Maybe add another constraint that $A$,$B$,$C$ are positive-semi definite and $D$ is positive definite, thus the trace is constrained to be positive.